# Installing pecl_http in xubuntu

Tags: php, http, pecl

As per title, I am simply trying to install pecl_http extension for php in ubuntu.

So I did what makes most sense:

```
andreas@earl ~ $ sudo pecl install pecl_http
downloading pecl_http-1.6.6.tgz ...
Starting to download pecl_http-1.6.6.tgz (173,645 bytes)
.....................................done: 173,645 bytes
71 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20041225
Zend Module Api No:      20060613
Zend Extension Api No:   220060519
 1. whether to enable cURL HTTP requests; specify libcurl directory : yes

1-1, 'all', 'abort', or Enter to continue: 
 1. whether to enable support for gzencoded/deflated message bodies; specify zlib directory : yes

1-1, 'all', 'abort', or Enter to continue: 
 1. whether to enable response content type guessing; specify libmagic directory : no

1-1, 'all', 'abort', or Enter to continue: 
 1. whether to depend on extensions which have been built shared : yes

1-1, 'all', 'abort', or Enter to continue: 
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-root/pecl_http-1.6.6
running: /tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-curl-requests --with-http-zlib-compression --with-http-magic-mime=no --with-http-shared-deps

checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gcc... gcc

.... <snip>

checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getdomainname... yes
checking for getservbyport... yes
checking for getservbyname... yes
checking for zlib.h... found in /usr
checking for zlib version >= 1.2.0.4... 1.2.3.3
checking for curl/curl.h... not found
configure: error: could not find curl/curl.h
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-curl-requests --with-http-zlib-compression --with-http-magic-mime=no --with-http-shared-deps' failed
```

so Ok, I don't have curl in the system, so I do

```
andreas@earl ~ $ sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Curl installed fine, so I tried installing php5-http again, but still the same error.

Anyone could share a light please? :(

-aw

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The message you are getting is not indicating that the PHP curl package is missing.

Instead, the problem is that you don't seem to have the "system" curl package -- or, at least, not in its "development" version, that contains the files required to compile `pecl_http`.

Judging from a quick `apt-cache search` :

```
$ LANG=en apt-cache search libcurl dev
libcurl4-gnutls-dev - Development files and documentation for libcurl (GnuTLS)
libcurl4-openssl-dev - Development files and documentation for libcurl (OpenSSL)
...
```

You probably have to install either `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` or `libcurl4-openssl-dev`.

(The last time I compiled PHP, I installed the first one of those, and it allowed me to compile PHP with curl support enabled)

Answer (score 10):

or.. just `sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev` will provide `curl/curl.h` and your `pecl_http` installation will continue

Answer (score 2):

This is worked on my Ubuntu 12.10

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-openssl-dev
sudo pecl install -a pecl_http

sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=http.so' > /etc/php5/mods-available/http.ini"
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/http.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/
```

You will need to restart your web server, to have this module loaded.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
or
sudo service nginx restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Late but that solved my problem on Ubuntu 13.04:

`sudo apt-get install -y curl libcurl3 libcurl4-gnutls-dev libmagic-dev` then `sudo pecl install pecl_http`.

Credits: http://web.onassar.com/blog/2012/07/15/installing-pecl-http-package-on-ubuntu-11-10/